# Protection on Dell notebook power supply

Tags: power-supply, boost

[Beware: i'm a electronics-starter]

Hello, i built a variable power supply using a DPS5005 and a [Sainsmart boost converter](https://www.sainsmart.com/products/dc-dc-converter-boost-8-32v-to-9-46v) to get 42V.
I'm using an old dell notebook PSU (DF266 Output: 19.5V 4.62A) which worked fine with the DPS5005 only but with the boost converter keeps shutting off (9/10 times).

Is this caused by a high initial current draw from the boost converter?
(Also, why exactly is it drawing very high initial current?)
And (how) can i fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A boost converter requires an initial charging current and power that will exceed the rated power for steady state.

Therefore you have two options at least. Return the unit or program or design a soft start. The output voltage is programmable maybe  can be incremented slowly or an inrush current limiter ICL, may be inserted on the input to limit the surge  current. These protection devices are inexpensive and have a large negative temperature coefficient, NTC For resistance.